# Randomly orientated lines drawn off a random point in python

Tags: python, random, line, intersection, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create python program that has several vertical lines which act as boundaries where randomly generated points or "dots" (as referred to in the code) which draw a straight line at a random degree. If the straight line intersects with one of the vertical "boundaries" I want to make it change colour. I have a picture of what I am trying to achieve which will probably explain my situation a bit clearer. The code I post below has drawn the "vertical boundaries" and has the points randomly generated within the region, however that is where I am stuck.

What I am aiming to achieve:

[Example of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofd7f.png)

My current Code:

```
setup(750,750)
screen_size = 750
max_coord = (screen_size - 30) / 2
### change the number of dots you have via that variable
num_dots = 500
bgcolor('yellow')
dot_size=5


reset() # Create an empty window 
pi = Turtle()
hideturtle()

def parallel_lines(number):
    pi.pensize(2)
    pi.pencolor('black')
    width = pi.window_width()
    height = pi.window_height()
    pi.setheading(90)
    pi.penup()
    pi.setposition(width/-2, height/-2)
for i in range(1, number +2):
    pi.pendown()
    pi.forward(height)
    pi.penup()
    pi.setposition(width/-2+i*(width/(number+1)),height/-2)
parallel_lines(7)

## centre turtle back in the middle of the page
goto(0,0)

### list to hold the dots
x_coords = []
y_coords = []
### Draw the dots via randomint

penup()
color("blue")
for dot_num in range(num_dots):
    dot_pos_x = randint (-max_coord, max_coord)
    dot_pos_y = randint (-max_coord, max_coord)
    goto(dot_pos_x, dot_pos_y)
    dot(dot_size)
    x_coords.append(dot_pos_x)
    y_coords.append(dot_pos_y)

done()
```

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help.

Comment: After you draw the dots, you have to draw your line. You can create a random direction, just like you created a random x and y position, turn your turtle in that direction and move there. To figure out the color you only need to consider the x-coordinate of your dot position and your end line position. If it crosses one of the parallel lines x-coordinates, then you should change its color. You can check if you cross one of the lines, e.g. by storing the line x positions produced in parallel_lines() and checking for x-intersection.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an implementation of the program the OP describes.  If there is a line intersection, it uses Python 3 turtle's *undo* feature to remove the line and redraw it in the alternate color:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint, randrange

SCREEN_SIZE = 750
PLANK_COUNT = 8
PINHEAD_SIZE = 5

FLOOR_COLOR = "yellow"
DEFAULT_COLOR = "blue"
CROSSING_COLOR = "red"

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(SCREEN_SIZE, SCREEN_SIZE)
screen.bgcolor(FLOOR_COLOR)

# configure numbers to replicate Lazzarini's setup

NUMBER_PINS = 3408
PIN_LENGTH = 78.125
PLANK_WIDTH = screen.window_width() / PLANK_COUNT

def parallel_lines(turtle, width, height):

    turtle.penup()
    turtle.setheading(90)

    turtle.sety(height / -2)

    x_coordinates = []

    for i in range(PLANK_COUNT + 1):
        x = i * PLANK_WIDTH - width / 2

        turtle.setx(x)
        turtle.pendown()
        turtle.forward(height)
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.left(180)

        x_coordinates.append(x)

    return x_coordinates


pi = Turtle(visible=False)
pi.speed("fastest")

x_coordinates = parallel_lines(pi, screen.window_width(), screen.window_height())

def crosses(x0, x1, coordinates):
    for coordinate in coordinates:
        if x0 <= coordinate <= x1 or x1 <= coordinate <= x0:
            return True
    return False

previous_crossings = crossings = 0

max_coord = screen.window_width() / 2

for pin in range(NUMBER_PINS):
    x0, y0 = randint(-max_coord, max_coord), randint(-max_coord, max_coord)

    pi.color(DEFAULT_COLOR)
    pi.goto(x0, y0)
    pi.dot(PINHEAD_SIZE)
    pi.setheading(randrange(360))
    pi.pendown()
    pi.forward(PIN_LENGTH)

    if crosses(x0, pi.xcor(), x_coordinates):
        pi.undo()
        pi.color(CROSSING_COLOR)
        pi.dot(PINHEAD_SIZE)
        pi.forward(PIN_LENGTH)

        crossings += 1

    pi.penup()

    if previous_crossings != crossings:
        estimate = (2 * PIN_LENGTH * pin) / (PLANK_WIDTH * crossings)
        print(estimate)
        previous_crossings = crossings

screen.exitonclick()
```

**Now for the rest of the story.**  What the OP didn't mention is that this is a drawing of planks in a floor, and we're dropping pins onto it, keeping track of how many cross lines in the flooring, as a means of estimating the value of PI (π)!

Read about [Buffon's needle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon's_needle) for details.  The gist is the probability of a pin crossing a line is a function of PI so we can turn the equation around, drop actual (or virtual) pins, to estimate PI.

[image]

The program outputs the running estimate for PI (π), based on pins dropped so far, to the console:

```
...
3.121212121212121
3.1215970961887476
3.1370772946859904
3.134418324291742
3.131768953068592
3.1381381381381384
3.1384892086330933
3.1358467983243568
3.1451612903225805
3.1454979129397733
3.1458333333333335
3.1491384432560903
3.1465005931198102
3.1438721136767316
3.144208037825059
3.144542772861357
3.1419316843345113
```